# Material-ui icon themes

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

[Material.io/icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline) supports different themes for their icons.

Can I change the theme for the icon when using these icons?

```
import AccessAlarmIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *"themed"* icons, append the theme name to the icon name. For example with your icon:

```js
  import { AccessAlarmIconTwoTone } from '@material-ui/icons';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can doing following:

```
<AccessAlarmIcon className={classes.customIcon} />
```

where you should create a `styles` (with customIcon: { cssProperty: value } )var with your styles and export your component with material-ui withStyles(styles)(ReactComponent) function, or just change color:

```
<AccessAlarmIcon color='primary' />
```

Comment: How can I set the style to "Outlined" or "Two-Tone"?